# Mysql Query of 2 tables with values using commas , matching same values using comma separator

Tags: mysql, sql

I continue the work of a project from the previous programmer, there is a problem in the query because the string data type is separated by commas, and must be in the query.

Is it possible to query from 2 tables with results like this?

Table User

| id | name | Skill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person A | skill A, skill B, skill C |
| 2 | Person B | skill B, skill C, skill D |
| 3 | Person C | skill C, skill D |
| 4 | Person D | skill E, skill F |
| 5 | Person E | skill A, skill E |
| 6 | Person F | skill A, skill C |
| 7 | Person G | skill G, skill H, skill X, skill Y, skill Z |

Table Jobs

| id | jobs skill |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | skill C, skill D, skill G |

Result Query

| name |
| --- |
| Person A |
| Person B |
| Person C |
| Person F |
| Person G |

Comment: which MySQL / MariaDB version you are using ?

Comment: How many skills would you match for each job? If this number is fixed (e.g. three like in the example) you could work with `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function as explained in https://database.guide/how-the-regexp_substr-function-works-in-mysql/. You can also work with a simpler one: `SUBSRT_INDEX` as explained in https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

Comment: Parse one of CSVs (`Jobs.JobSkill` recommended), test against separate values, then group.

Comment: Mysql version 5.7

Comment: unlimited skill

Comment: Does there exists a table which contains complete skills list, one value per row? Does there exists max. possible skills amount per `Jobs.JobSkill` value? really, not in theory.

Answer (score 0):

If it weren't for the "unlimited skill" expectation, this could be a relatively simple query. That said, here's something that will get you the result that you seek.

Replace the desired skill expectations midway down in the line that starts `WHERE zz.skill IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT zz.`name`
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT uu.`name`, TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(uu.`skill`, ',', num.`idx`), ',', -1)) as `skill`
          FROM `User` uu CROSS JOIN
               (SELECT (h*100+t*10+u+1) as `idx`
                  FROM (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a,
                       (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b,
                       (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c) num) zz
 WHERE zz.`skill` IN (SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('skill A, skill B, skill C', ',', num.`idx`), ',', -1)) as `skill`
                        FROM (SELECT (h*100+t*10+u+1) as `idx`
                                FROM (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a,
                                     (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b,
                                     (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c) num
                       HAVING `skill` <> '')
 ORDER BY zz.`name`;
```

**Caveats:**

1. You do not *technically* have unlimited skill options here. Each record can have up to 1,000. If you need more, you will need to expand the ugly `CROSS JOIN` number generator.
2. This is not the most memory-efficient design. It is not recommended to run on tens of thousands of records at a time.

**Source Data:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `User`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (
    `id`        int(11)       UNSIGNED NOT NULL    ,
    `name`      varchar(40)            NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    `skill`     varchar(256)           NOT NULL    DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `User` (`id`, `name`, `skill`)
VALUES (1, 'Person A', 'skill A, skill B, skill C'),
       (2, 'Person B', 'skill B, skill C, skill D'),
       (3, 'Person C', 'skill C, skill D'),
       (4, 'Person D', 'skill E, skill F'),
       (5, 'Person E', 'skill A, skill E'),
       (6, 'Person F', 'skill A, skill C'),
       (7, 'Person G', 'skill G, skill H, skill X, skill Y, skill Z');
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this problem is to split each skill into separate lines, which does not require hard coding. However, no matter what method you use, you must first have a large enough digital table. There are many ways to create it like this

```sql
create table bignum as 
select @rn:=@rn+1 rn
  from information_schema.COLUMNS t1,
       (select @rn:=0) t2
 limit 100;
```

Then you can do this

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `User`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (
    `id`        int(11)       UNSIGNED NOT NULL    ,
    `name`      varchar(40)            NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    `skill`     varchar(256)           NOT NULL    DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `User` (`id`, `name`, `skill`)
VALUES (1, 'Person A', 'skill A, skill B, skill C'),
       (2, 'Person B', 'skill B, skill C, skill D'),
       (3, 'Person C', 'skill C, skill D'),
       (4, 'Person D', 'skill E, skill F'),
       (5, 'Person E', 'skill A, skill E'),
       (6, 'Person F', 'skill A, skill C'),
       (7, 'Person G', 'skill G, skill H, skill X, skill Y, skill Z');

select t1.*,
       trim(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`skill`, ',', t2.rn), ',', -1))
  from user t1,
       bignum t2
 where length(t1.skill) - length(replace(t1.skill, ',', '')) + 1 >= t2.rn
 order by t1.id
;
```

As for the rest, I believe you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix your data model!  Storing multiple values in a string is just a bad way to store data.  For many reasons.  That should be where your effort goes.

Because you are looking for *any* match, you are a bit lucky, because you can use regular expressions:

```
select u.*
from user u join
     jobs j
     on u.skill regexp replace(j.skill, ', ', '|');
```

Note:  This assumes that the skill lists do not contain any special regular expression characters.  It also assumes that the skills don't "overlap", so you one skill does not match another.  An example of a problem might be `SQL` and `MySQL`.  This can be fixed by making the regular expression a bit more complicated.  These problems can be fixed by doctoring the regular expression, but I don't know if that complication is necessary.